# What is the best approach to render complex layout in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have two layouts that are changed based on a boolean condition. The condition's name is `showMap`. So here is what I am doing.

```
 <Grid container xs={12} md={If(props.showMap, 4, 12)} 
    lg={If(props.showMap, 4, 12)} 
    xl={If(props.showMap, 3, 12)} 
    spacing={If(props.showMap, 0, 2)} item={true}>
      .....
 </Grid>
```

And there is a lot of code written like this (nested inside the grid) to avoid code duplication. But it has effected the performance as it takes some time to re render and change the layout.

Is there a better approach for this type of conditional complex rendering in React?

The implementation of `If` is as follows:

```
function If(value, ifTrue, ifFalse) {
  return value ? ifTrue : ifFalse
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could define two config consts, one with values for when showMap is true and one for when it is false

Inside render you can do `let gridConfig = { this.props.showMap ? config1 : config2}

When returning the grid just do `lg={gridConfig.lg}`

This will reduce the number of `IF` calls but unfortunately whenever the state updates react re-renders. So I am not sure if the `IF` is causing the performance issue

Comment: But I think the major issue is with the number of re renders unfortunately.

Comment: @MohhamadHasham Maybe the lifecycle method `componentShouldUpdate()` might be useful then

You can stop react from re-rendering when a state updates with a conditional. 
https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/using_should_component_update.html